# How is ID work in asp: TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm very new in .net c#, just a question here to  about the following code. I have wrote a code to display a text box on the screen as below:

> ```
>   <asp:TextBox ID="sUnit" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" />
> ```

But somehow I failed to using jqueryto assign a value into this textbox:

> ```
>  $('#sUnit').val('test');
> ```

Surprisingly when I view the source code, and it show me the ID for the text box is like below:

```
<input name="ctl00$cplh$sUnit" type="text" maxlength="12" id="ctl00_cplh_sUnit" style="width:3em;" />
```

Does anyone know how can I get the textbox ID so that I can assigned the value into the textbox?

Hope my question is not sound stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0, set the `ClientIDMode` to `static`.

For older versions, use 
`$('#<%= sUnit.ClientID %>')`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that UI elements containing these controls are being rendered by ASP.NET, those containers that implement [INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) generate the prefix that should be prefixed as per their scope.

From the MSDN line mentioned above:

> Any control that implements this
>   interface creates a new namespace in
>   which all child control ID attributes
>   are guaranteed to be unique within an
>   entire application. The marker
>   provided by this interface allows
>   unique naming of the dynamically
>   generated server control instances
>   within the Web server controls that
>   support data binding.

One suggestion in order to find the control itself might be to use the [first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), where you controls are contained within a regular `div`. An example to find elements of type `input` might look something like:

```
$('#MyDiv').first('input[type="text"]')
```

Comment: Why `first` and not e.g. `find`?